# JSON Schema OneOf Cascading

Tags: json, jsonschema

What I am asking myself is if I can cascade multiple 'oneOf' or maybe there is a better way to make my Cases Valid.

## I am Trying to validate the following:

Use definition of ObjectA or ObjectB as Single Objects or an Array of a them

### Case 1:

Using only definition of ObjectA

```
{
 "X": "test"
}
```

### Case 2:

Using only definition of ObjectB

```
{
 "Y": "test"
}
```

### Case 3:

Using definition of ObjectA or ObjectB in an Array

```
[
 {
  "X": "test"
 },
 {
  "Y": "test"
 }
]
```

## Case 4:

Using definition of ObjectA twice in an Array

```
[
 {
  "X": "test"
 },
 {
  "X": "test"
 }
]
```

## Schema:

I tryed using this schema, the IntelliSense of MonacoEditor is working well but I still get the Error/Warning: "Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate."

```
{
 "definitions": {
  "objectA": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
   "X": {
    type: "string"
   }
  }
 },
  "objectB": {
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
    "Y": {
     type: "string"
    }
   }
  }
 },
 "oneOf":
  [
   {
    "oneOf":
     [
      {
       "$ref": "#definitions/objectA"
      },
      {
       "$ref": "#definitions/objectB"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "type": "array",
     "items": 
      {
       "oneOf":
        [
         {
          "$ref": "#definitions/objectA"
         },
         {
          "$ref": "#definitions/objectB"
         }
        ]        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## Error/Warning:

"Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your X property in objectA and Y property en objectB are not required, so an empty object, that is { }, validates against both.

Also, if you want an array with objectA and objectY to be valid, you need to use anyOf instead of oneOf.

```
{
 "definitions": {
   "objectA": {
     "type": "object",
     "properties": {
       "X": {
         "type": "string"
       }
     },
     "required": ["X"]
   },
   "objectB": {
     "type": "object",
     "properties": {
       "Y": {
         "type": "string"
       }
     },
     "required": ["Y"]
   }
 },
 "oneOf":
  [
   {"$ref": "#/definitions/objectA"},
   {"$ref": "#/definitions/objectB"},
   {
     "type": "array",
     "minItems": 1,
     "items":
     {
       "anyOf":
       [
         {"$ref": "#/definitions/objectA"},
         {"$ref": "#/definitions/objectB"}
       ]        
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

I added the minItems if you don't want an empty array to validate.